# How to load a new scene in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I am using A-Frame (JavaScript library). I would  like to load a new scene when user clicks into a certain component in the current scene. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [A-Frame Template Component](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/template). Notably the [Swapping Example](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/template/examples/swapping).

You can either define your separate scenes within script tags or within separate files. Here is an example with script tag templating:

```
<a-scene>
  <!-- Templates. -->
  <a-assets>
    <script id="scene1" type="text/html">
      <a-box></a-box>
    </script>
    <script id="scene2" type="text/html">
      <a-sphere></a-sphere>
    </script>
  </a-assets>

  <a-entity template="src: #box"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Then when you want to change your scene, change the `src`:

```
<a-entity template="src: #sphere"></a-entity>
```

Here is an example component to programmatically change template `src` on interval: https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/blob/master/components/template/examples/swapping/components/template-looper.js

Mainly it will be `el.setAttribute('template', 'src', '#sphere');`

For other components that could assist changing the src:

- [Event Set Component](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/event-set) can help listen to your mouseenter and change the `src` in response.
- The template component also comes with `template-set` component that will change the template on an event.

Comment: Can I change template src (from ngokevin/aframe-template-component) using  aframe-event-set-component

Comment: Yeah, I imagine you should be able too. The provided `template-set` component can also change templates in response to events.