# @aframe.io how do I change a-scene

Tags: aframe

How do I change a-scene? One scene to another.

```
<!-- scene 1 -->
<a-scene scale="0.2 0.2 0.2">
  <a-assets altspace >
    <img id="bg1" src="offbg.jpg">
  </a-assets>

  <a-sky src="#bg1"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
<!-- scene 2 -->
<a-scene scale="0.2 0.2 0.2">
    <a-assets altspace >
      <img id="bg2" src="offbg2.jpg">
    </a-assets>

    <a-sky src="#bg2"></a-sky>
  </a-scene>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738147/how-to-load-a-new-scene-in-a-frame

Answer (score 0):

Guide on swapping out background images with JS: https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/guides/building-a-360-image-gallery.html

You can do `document.querySelector('a-sky').setAttribute('src', 'newimage.jpg')` to change the src.